# Condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]$ to be equal

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Consider real numbers $a_{m, n}$ for $n = 1 ,2,...$ and $m = 1, 2,...,$ and assume that inner and outer sums in the expressions
> \begin{align}
>         A:= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]\\
>         B:= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]\\
>     \end{align}
> are absolutely convergent.
>
> (1) Give an example that shows we may have $A \neq B$.
>
> (2) Under what reasonable additional assumption on $a_{n, m}$ can we conclude $A = B$?

Thanks, Brian for the suggestions. For part (1) Let $a_{n,n} = 1$, $a_{n+1, n} = -1$ and all the other values of $a_{m, n}$ be $0$. Then we have
\begin{align}
A&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n,n} + a_{n+1, n})\\
&= (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + \cdots \\
&= 0\\
B&=  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\right]\\
    &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty (a_{m,m-1} + a_{m,m})\\
    & = 1 + (-1+1) + (-1+ 1) + \cdots \\
    &= 1
\end{align}

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at $(a_{m,n})$ such that $a_{m,n} = 0$ except when $m=n$ or $m=n+1$.  (Note that in such series, the inner sum is trivially absolutely convergent, so you'll need to construct the nonzero values in a way that makes the outer sum absolutely convergent)

Comment: What is meant by absolute convergence? The absolute values are around the inner sums, not the $a_{n,m}$'s?

Comment: I guess the wording of the question isn't very clear. but what @BrianMoehring said is probably right

Comment: @BrianMoehring I made an edit in response to your suggestions. please take a look

Comment: That is Fubini Theorem for sum. You can always change the summation order if $a_{n,m}\geq 0$ The latter is well-known Fubini-Tonelli. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: this is true by virtue of addition being commutative

Comment: As a further hint/[barely disguised solution], we have $$1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + \cdots \neq (1 + -1) + (1 + -1) + (1 + -1) + \cdots$$ (and no, you cannot have either series diverge, as that would contradict the absolute convergence of both the inner and outer sums)

Comment: @BrianMoehring These sums are not absolutely convergent though...

Comment: The series $1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + \cdots$ is literally just $1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots$.  Similarly, the series $(1 + -1) + (1 + -1) + (1+-1) + \cdots$ is just $0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots$.  Are you saying either is not absolutely convergent?  This is, in essence, the difference between saying both the inner and outer sums are absolutely convergent and saying the double sum is absolutely convergent: both of these [outer] sums are trivially absolutely convergent, but the double sum, which would be represented by removing the parentheses, is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Ohh I misinterpreted that sequence for some reason I thought 1, -1, 1, -1,... were the terms in which case absolute convergence would be convergence of 1+1+1+1+1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Fubini Theorem for sum. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

You can always change the summation order if $a_{n,m}\geq 0$: This is the well-known **Fubini-Tonelli**.

In general if $$\sum\sum_{n,m} |a_{n,m}|<\infty$$ you can always change the summation order. This is the well-known **Fubini**.

Comment: To use Fubini according to the link you sent you only need the double sum to be absolutely convergent. Using the terminology in my problem statement is this different than having the inner and our sums each be absolutely convergent?